# Establish a connection to the NAS with Yad

Tags: connection, nas, yad

My attempts to connect the PC to a NAS have only been partially successful so far. First, a directory is to be searched for under "yad". If it contains files (true), the status "activated" is reached and is visible in a column. Otherwise the status "deactivated (false) should be displayed.
I have already found a part for the script on the net. The following code already shows me the result /home/$USER/xyz after selecting a folder, where "xyz" corresponds to the folder on my NAS. Up to this point, the following code works very well.

```
#!/bin/bash

test -e /tmp/yadpipe03 && rm -f /tmp/yadpipe03

# Named pipe initialization
export PIPE_03=/tmp/yadpipe03
mkfifo $PIPE_03
exec 3<> $PIPE_03

function load_data
{
  DIRS="$(yad --file --multiple --width=800 --height=600 \
         --directory --title="Select folder")"

  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS="|"

  [[ ! -z "$DIRS" ]] && YAD_DATA=($(for DIR in "$DIRS";do echo "$DIR";done ))

  IFS=$OIFS

  for DATA in "${YAD_DATA[@]}";do
      echo True     # Adds "True" for the checklist column
      echo "${DATA}"
  done
}
export -f load_data

function clear_all
{
  echo -e '\f'
}
export -f clear_all

# Main Dialog
Record=($(yad --list --checklist --separator="|" --grid-lines=hor \
    --width=1200 --height=800 --center \
    --title="Set up connections to the NAS" \
    --text="Example" \
    --column "Select" --column "Folder" --column "Status" \
    --button="Add folder!gtk-add":'bash -c "load_data > $PIPE_03"' \
    --button="Activate!gtk-connect":'bash -c "load_data > $PIPE_03"' \
    --button="Deactivate!gtk-disconnect":'bash -c "load_data > $PIPE_03"' \
    --button="Clear!gtk-clear":'bash -c "clear_all > $PIPE_03"' \
    --button="OK!gtk-ok":0 \
    --listen --print-all < $PIPE_03))
Action=$?

echo ${Record[@]}
```

From the result - `echo ${Record[@]}` - the name of the folder should now be filtered. Then, by pressing the "Activate" or "Deactivate" buttons, the corresponding command (which I know) and the status are written to a file using the case command. If now possible, the status should be updated in the Yad window. The next time the folder is selected at the latest, a current view should be provided.

As I am not a recognised expert, I am looking for help here.

Thank you very much

Comment: It is not clear from your description what do you actually want to achieve. Please clarify it and state clearly what is the expected behavior, what is the current behavior and what you have trouble with.

Comment: Did I really explain it that badly? Well then I'll try again: You have kindly already corrected the code. The result after clicking on "ADD Folder" and then "OK" is as follows: "TRUE|/home/achim/myBackups|(null)|"

(I need help with this):

The folder name "myBackups" should be extracted from this. This name is then used by clicking on Activate or Deactivate.

z. B.

case $action in
mount /home/$USER/MyBackups (to activate the connection)

;; esac

or

case $action in
umount /home/$USER/MyBackups (to deactivate the connection)

;; esac

Comment: If possible, "Activated" or "Deactivated" should then be displayed under "Status" by refreshing the display. A special highlight would be if the status could also be seen when the script is restarted.

I hope it is now easier to understand.